# ¿Como debuguear un servicio en Android? no inicia Servicio

Tags: android, servicio

Lo que quiero es debuggear mi servicio en background de mi aplicación de android, pero nunca se ejecuta y no se a que se deba.

Esto esta en el manifest

```
  <service android:name=".utils.MyService" android:enabled="true"></service>
```

Esto es el oncreate del servicio

```
public void onCreate()
{
    android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected();
    android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected();
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Nunca se para en ninguna instrucción de mi método del servicio

Comment: David, es importante agregar como lo estas iniciando, eso me parece el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizar debugging en el proceso que realiza tu servicio, incluso puedes usar el [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) para imprimir valores durante la ejecución del mismo.

En el caso de la excepcion es preferible obtener el mensaje del error mediante el método `getMessage()`:

```
 Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex.getMessage());
```

En cuanto al problema principal, registrar tu servicio dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` no es suficiente para iniciar un servicio al ejecutar tu aplicación, para esto tiene que ser iniciado mediante un `Intent`, ejemplo:

```
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
startService(myService);
```